# Activity messed after playing YUV video use opengles on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es

I use opengl es with jni to play YUV video, the video is OK.

But when i close GLSurfaceView and return to main Activity.

The characters and images display in main Activity become messed.

All icons becomes black solid rectangle. All the characters becomes white solid rectangle.

The code look likes come from WebRTC and modified by someone else.
I'm a C programmer and not familiar with OpenGl. So it's a really big problem for me to solve this problem.

I create handle in JNI like this:

```
bool isAttached = false;
JNIEnv* env = NULL;
if (_jvm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
    // try to attach the thread and get the env
    // Attach this thread to JVM
    jint res = _jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

    // Get the JNI env for this thread
    if ((res < 0) || !env) {
        LOGE("%s: Could not attach thread to JVM (%d, %p)",
                __FUNCTION__, res, env);
        return -1;
    }
    isAttached = true;
}

// get the ViEAndroidGLES20 class
jclass javaRenderClassLocal = reinterpret_cast<jclass> (env->FindClass("com/wg/rgc/library/gl/ViEAndroidGLES20"));
if (!javaRenderClassLocal) {
    LOGE("%s: could not find ViEAndroidGLES20", __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

_javaRenderClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass> (env->NewGlobalRef(javaRenderClassLocal));
if (!_javaRenderClass) {
    LOGE("%s: could not create Java SurfaceHolder class reference",
            __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

// Delete local class ref, we only use the global ref
env->DeleteLocalRef(javaRenderClassLocal);
jmethodID cidUseOpenGL = env->GetStaticMethodID(_javaRenderClass,
        "UseOpenGL2",
        "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
if (cidUseOpenGL == NULL) {
    LOGE("%s: could not get UseOpenGL ID", __FUNCTION__);
    return false;
}
jboolean res = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(_javaRenderClass,
        cidUseOpenGL, (jobject) _ptrWindow);

// create a reference to the object (to tell JNI that we are referencing it
// after this function has returned)
_javaRenderObj = reinterpret_cast<jobject> (env->NewGlobalRef((jobject)_ptrWindow));
if (!_javaRenderObj)
{
    LOGE("%s: could not create Java SurfaceRender object reference",
            __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

// get the method ID for the ReDraw function
_redrawCid = env->GetMethodID(_javaRenderClass, "ReDraw", "()V");
if (_redrawCid == NULL) {
    LOGE("%s: could not get ReDraw ID", __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

_registerNativeCID = env->GetMethodID(_javaRenderClass,
        "RegisterNativeObject", "(J)V");
if (_registerNativeCID == NULL) {
    LOGE("%s: could not get RegisterNativeObject ID", __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

_deRegisterNativeCID = env->GetMethodID(_javaRenderClass,
        "DeRegisterNativeObject", "()V");
if (_deRegisterNativeCID == NULL) {
    LOGE("%s: could not get DeRegisterNativeObject ID",
            __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

JNINativeMethod nativeFunctions[2] = {
    { "DrawNative",
        "(J)V",
        (void*) &AndroidNativeOpenGl2Channel::DrawNativeStatic, },
    { "CreateOpenGLNative",
        "(JII)I",
        (void*) &AndroidNativeOpenGl2Channel::CreateOpenGLNativeStatic },
};
if (env->RegisterNatives(_javaRenderClass, nativeFunctions, 2) == 0) {
    LOGE("%s: Registered native functions", __FUNCTION__);
}
else {
    LOGE("%s: Failed to register native functions", __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

env->CallVoidMethod(_javaRenderObj, _registerNativeCID, (jlong) this);

if (isAttached) {
    if (_jvm->DetachCurrentThread() < 0) {
        LOGE("%s: Could not detach thread from JVM", __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

LOGE("%s done", __FUNCTION__);

if (_openGLRenderer.SetCoordinates(0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0) != 0) {
    return -1;
}

isAlreadyInit = 1;  //Init finish
return 0;
```

And i close this handle in JNI like this:

```
bool isAttached = false;
JNIEnv* env = NULL;
if (_jvm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
    // try to attach the thread and get the env
    // Attach this thread to JVM
    jint res = _jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

    // Get the JNI env for this thread
    if ((res < 0) || !env) {
        LOGE("%s: Could not attach thread to JVM (%d, %p)",
                __FUNCTION__, res, env);
        env = NULL;
    } else {
        isAttached = true;
    }
}

if (env && _deRegisterNativeCID) {
    env->CallVoidMethod(_javaRenderObj, _deRegisterNativeCID);
}

env->DeleteGlobalRef(_javaRenderObj);
env->DeleteGlobalRef(_javaRenderClass);

if (isAttached) {
    if (_jvm->DetachCurrentThread() < 0) {
        LOGE("%s: Could not detach thread from JVM",
                __FUNCTION__);
    }
}
```

The method  env->CallVoidMethod(_javaRenderObj, _deRegisterNativeCID); called Java method in Java src:

```
nativeFunctionLock.lock();
nativeFunctionsRegisted = false;
openGLCreated = false;
this.nativeObject = 0;
nativeFunctionLock.unlock();
```

The code in Java src looks like extends GLSurfaceView and implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer. In JNI the code registered some method as native method in Java.
The code is complicated for me to understand , but my boss request me fix this problem quickly.
I can't figure out why after playing YUV video , every image and characters become rectangles. How did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably delete the texture after rendering, you can try to keep them, and deallocate them when app terminated